# iOS 11.1 UIImagePickerController video crop start time not movable

Tags: ios, video, crop, ios11, notificationcenter

We are displaying a UIImagePickerController for users to choose (and crop) a video for use within our app. Recently users have been experiencing issues trying to crop videos, with the start time handle becoming almost impossible to drag.

[image: Handle]

It seems that the Photos app doesn't have this issue because the video timeline (and crop selection) is moved to the bottom of the screen.

[image]

I assume this has to do with the new notification centre gestures that were added for the iPhone X. I believe this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060895/top-and-bottom-of-ios-11-1-games-unresponsive-to-touch/47073994#47073994) is related to the issue we're experiencing.

Anyone else having this issue, or have a way to get around it? Since this is a stock UIViewController I can't see how we can get around the issue without building our own custom video picker/cropper.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I decided to disable the UIImagePickerController editing and catch the video path in the UIImagePIckerController's didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo, and then use UIVideoEditorController to edit the video. This is a quick example:

```
if UIVideoEditorController.canEditVideo(atPath: videoPath) {
    let editController = UIVideoEditorController()
    editController.videoPath = videoPath
    editController.delegate = self
    present(editController, animated:true)
}
```

For more information about UIVideoEditorController, check Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivideoeditorcontroller?