# UIImagePickerController on iPhone Left trim handle don't work

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode9

on iOS 11 when using UIImageViewController and allows editing turned on, and selects a video, I can't move left trim handle on iPhone but it works on iPad.

Is this a known problem? or do anyone know a workaround to get this to work?

This problem is also described here with images.
[iOS 11.1 UIImagePickerController video crop start time not movable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47127659/ios-11-1-uiimagepickercontroller-video-crop-start-time-not-movable?rq=1)

Comment: I do not know a solution, but just want to confirm that I have been experiencing this as well. Occasionally I am able to grab + move the left control but 95% of the the time it is not moveable.

Comment: I just filed a Bug with Apple.

Comment: I m also facing this issue... did you find a solution?

Comment: The bug was marked as an duplicate by A. so something is going on at A. to solve this it seams. I will keep you updated when something happens.