# Touches delayed at screen edge on iOS 11

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, touch, ios11

I recently updated my development iPhone 6 to iOS 11.1.2, and have noticed a strange behaviour that has appeared in regards to my touch controls.

I have UI elements at the top / bottom of the screen in Landscape mode, and they became unresponsive.

Further testing has shown that my UIViewController has a 1-2 second delay in calling the `touchesBegan:` method, but only at the edges of the screen.

Any idea how to stop the delay from happening? I've noticed some posts talking about 3d touch, however my current phone is too old to support that.

Comment: does it include a scroll view? there's a `delaysContentTouches` attribute in scroll views

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - All I know is that to get touchesBegan to be called at the edge of the screen, I have to hold my finger down for 1-2 seconds.

This is in the same zone of where if you touch and drag down, iOS calls the "earlier today" window down.

Oh and also, before the update, I never had any issues =S

Comment: Please add your answer as an actual answer rather than an edit. Self-answers are welcome.

Comment: Maybe you could also check if there are `UIGestureRecognizer`derived classes somewhere - These classes have  `delaysTouchesBegan` and `delaysTouchesEnd` fields (even if 1-2 seconds seems very long...)

Comment: See this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060895/top-and-bottom-of-ios-11-1-games-unresponsive-to-touch